# How can a custom NSManagedObject be created without store it in context?

Tags: core-data

How can I create a custom managed object, but without to save, just keep it in the memory and when app stops, temporary managed object can be dealloched too. But same time other managed objects I need to save.

Comment: You could follow the pattern described at http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ and create temporary worker contexts that you can use to create throwaway managed objects that you don't save. For objects you want to save, just make sure to save the worker contexts used to create them. This could be potentially problematic if you want interactions between these temporary managed objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities depending on how your app works.

One is to just create the object and just not insert it. It's just that simple. Pass a nil value for the context.

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel =
    [[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"EntityName"];
NSManagedObject *myObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

If you later want to insert the object, use `[NSManagedObjectContext insertObject:]`.

Another is to create an in-memory Core Data store. Create a second persistent store, but replace `NSSQLiteStoreType` with `NSInMemoryStoreType`. Then create and use objects as usual. When the app exits, the in-memory store will just disappear with all of its objects.